# How to list the files and folders that are not present in each other without comparing the contents of the file?

Tags: macos, command-line, diff

I am currently using `diff -rq /dir1 /dir2` to check for contents that are not present in each other. But this compares the contents of the file which takes forever if using a disc and hard drive. I want to list differences only by checking the name. How to do that in mac? Is there any tool that can do this? Do any nifty custom script? Thanks.

Comment: Consideration: File name ≠ file contents. If two files have the same name, but not the same contents, would that be a false positive for your case, or are the contents of the files actually not important?

Comment: Content of files are not important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to check with `find` and `comp`.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <folder1> <folder2>"
    exit 1
fi

folder1_path="$1"
folder2_path="$2"

# List all files in first folder
find "$folder1_path" -type f | sed "s#${folder1_path}/##" | sort > files_in_folder1.txt

# List all files in second folder
find "$folder2_path" -type f | sed "s#${folder2_path}/##" | sort > files_in_folder2.txt

echo 'Files in folder1 that are not in folder2:'
comm -23 files_in_folder1.txt files_in_folder2.txt

echo ''
echo 'Files in folder2 that are not in folder1:'
comm -23 files_in_folder2.txt files_in_folder1.txt

# Clean up
rm files_in_folder1.txt files_in_folder2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to list differences only by checking the name. How to do that in mac?

If only the directory structures and file names are important…

You can use the *list directory contents* command (`ls`) to generate the recursive structure of each directory in two subshells, then compare those outputs using `diff`:

```txt
% diff <(cd a; ls -AFR1) <(cd b; ls -AFR1)
```

---

Given two directories `a` and `b` with identical structures:

```txt
% ls -AFR1 a
hello.txt
sub/

a/sub:
hello.txt
```

Running the above command produces the following output:

```txt
% diff <(cd a; ls -AFR1) <(cd b; ls -AFR1)

% echo $?
0
```

And modifying one will show the desired diff:

```txt
% rm b/sub/hello.txt

% diff <(cd a; ls -AFR1) <(cd b; ls -AFR1)
5d4
< hello.txt

% echo $?                                 
1
```

Descriptions of the `ls` arguments from the manpage:

> ```txt
> -A      Include directory entries whose names begin with a dot (‘.’)
>         except for . and ...  Automatically set for the super-user unless
>         -I is specified.
>
> -F      Display a slash (‘/’) immediately after each pathname that is a
>         directory, an asterisk (‘*’) after each that is executable, an at
>         sign (‘@’) after each symbolic link, an equals sign (‘=’) after
>         each socket, a percent sign (‘%’) after each whiteout, and a
>         vertical bar (‘|’) after each that is a FIFO.
>
> -R      Recursively list subdirectories encountered.
>
> -1      (The numeric digit “one”.) Force output to be one entry per line.
>         This is the default when output is not to a terminal.  (-l)
>         output, and don't materialize dataless directories when listing
>         them.
> ```

---

However, two files sharing the same name doesn't mean that their contents don't differ, so only use a name-based approach as a fast early step to detect overall changes between directory roots, and not to rule out the lack of change.